# Does a 4-pin mini-DIN S-Video out to HDMI in cable exist?

Tags: hdmi, s-video, av-cable

I'm looking for an cable (adapter or something) that can connect a

**4-pin mini-DIN S-Video out**

[image: 4-pin mini-DIN connector]

to a:

**HDMI in**

[image]

> The reason being I have an ancient piece of specialized equipment (no it's not a DVD- player)
>   that only outputs to
>   S-Video (4-pin) and the modern display only accepts HDMI input. *By the way, this is not a home theater question.*

So far I've only managed to obtain a **7-pin mini-DIN S-Video out** to **HDMI in**.

Does anyone know where to get a **4-pin mini-DIN S-Video out** to **HDMI in** cable (if there's such a thing)?

Comment: You can't do it simply with a cable. HDMI is digital, S video is just b+w and color analog analog signals. YOu would need some sort of adapter with a graphics chipset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following appears to offer a 4-pin S-Video to HDMI conversion:

http://www.svideo.com/sv2hdmi.html

A similar item, but with a bit more detail on what it supports:

http://www.keene.co.uk/electronic/tv-one/tv-one-1t-vs-622-video--stereo-audio-to-hdmi-conv/1TVS622.html

Comment: +1 @Sliff, thanks for the quick answer. I'll check them out. superuser.com is amazing. ;-)